# AI platform R notebook

Tags: r, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, google-ai-platform

I have used RStudio to submit a job a few months ago to cloudml (AI platform) and it was successful.

Today I tried to use AI platform notebook to submit the same job but I get:

```
"ERROR: (gcloud.ai-platform.jobs.submit.training) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Field: runtime_version Error: The specified runtime version '1.9' with the Python version ''"
```

I even ran which python in the terminal and then in the R env.:

```
library(reticulate)  
use_python("result of the which python")
```

I tried R in the terminal as well and get the same error.

I don't know if it helps or not but the previous run and this one were in different regions.
us-central was successful
australia-southeast1 was getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because as of **March 16, 2020**, you can no longer create training jobs that use [runtime version 1.9](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/runtime-version-list#1.9). You can try submitting the job with [version 1.15](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/runtime-version-list#1.15) which is the only Tensorflow 1.x version that is currently supported for training jobs. It is still possible though that you may experience errors due to incompatibilities in the code.